# How to add jquery mobile loading mask

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios

I am new in jquery mobile, i have implemented some features in an application for ipad. Well i used to transacte with database the following code:

http://pastebin.com/p9FJa3Ym

I need to add a loading mask to my page before showing results. Can anyone help me on how to do that and where to put the code please?

Answer (score 0):

If you checkout the jQuery Mobile website, there's a method to show the page loading message.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/methods.html

Comment: Thank you , but i think this is not what i need, i had i look at the documentation and found that page loading is used when loading external pages. I need to show a loading mask when i get some content from database because, the actuel state is that we should wait some moment before i can see anything in the interface